# Show that: $(i) M \cong N$ and $G/M \cong G/N$ >or >$(ii) M \cong G/N$ and $G/M \cong N$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group and assume that $\{1\} < N \lhd G$ such that $N$ and $G/N$ are simple. Assume that also $M \unlhd G$ such that $M$ and $G/M$ are simple. Show that:
>
> $(i) M \cong N$ and $G/M \cong G/N$
>
> or
>
> $(ii) M \cong G/N$ and $G/M \cong N$

We know that $M, N, G/M,$ and $G/N$ are all simple groups, so the only subgroups are $\{1_G\}, M \leqslant M$,  $\{1_G\}, N \leqslant N$,  $\{1_G\}, G/M \leqslant G/M$, and $\{1_G\}, G/M \leqslant G$.

A toolbox that I compiled from my lecture notes:

> $I.$ Theorem (Fundamental Theorem of Homomorphisms). If $f: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism and $N \unlhd G \subseteq ker(f)$, then there is a unique group homormorphism $\bar{f}:G/N \to H$ such that $\bar{f} \circ \varphi = f$ where $\varphi: G \to G/N$ denotes the natural epimorphism.

Probably not going to be useful directly, but used to prove $II.$

> $II.$ Corollary (First Isomorphism Theorem). Follows from setting $N:= ker(f)$. If $f: G \to H$ is a group homomorphism, then $G/ker(f) \cong im(f)$.
>
> $III.$ Theorem (Second Isomorphism Theorem). Let $G$ be a group and let $H \leqslant G$ and $N \unlhd G$. Then $N \unlhd HN = NH$, $H \cap N \unlhd H$ and $H/(H \cap N) \cong HN/N$ with the property that $\phi(a(H \cap N)) = aN$ for all $ a \in H$.
>
> $IV.$ Theorem (Third Isomorphism Theorem). Let $G$ be a group, let $N, H \unlhd G$ and assume that $N \subseteq H$. Then $(G/N)/(H/N) \cong G/H$.

Work so far:
Suppose that $M = N$, then clearly $M \cong N$. Furthermore, this implies that $G/M = G/N$, since $G$ is partitioned into identical left cosets. Thus $G/M \cong G/N$. Now assume that $M \ne N$. Applying $III$ (Second Isomorphism Theorem), we have that $N/(M \cap N) \cong (MN)/M$ and $M/(M \cap N) \cong (MN)/N$, where in each case we choose $N \leqslant G$ or $M \leqslant G$, and then select the other to be our normal subgroup. If we select $N \leqslant G$, then $M \cap N$ is normal in $M$, and if we select  $M \leqslant G$, then $M \cap N$ is normal in $N$. Since $M$ and $N$ are simple, we have that $M \cap N = \{1_G \}$ (since we assumed $M \ne N$). Hence $N/\{1\} \cong N \cong (MN)/M$ and $M/\{1\} \cong M \cong (MN)/M$. How to show $MN \cong G$?

Comment: My thoughts: try to determine if $M \cap N$ and $MN$ are normal in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about $\pi:G \rightarrow G/N$. Then $\pi(M)$ is a subgroup of $G/N$. It is a normal subgroup because $\pi$ is surjective (show that).

If $\pi(M)=\{1\}$ then $M \subseteq N$ and so $M=N$ because $N$ is simple

If $\pi(M)\neq\{1\}$ then $\pi(M)=G/N$ (because $G/N$ is simple). Now note that 
$$
\pi|_M:M\rightarrow G/N
$$
is surjective with trivial kernel (because $M$ is simple).

[edit:]

Now if $g\in G$, then $gN=mN$ in $G/N$ (because $\pi|_M$ surjective), which implies $g=mn'$. $g$ was arbitrary, therefore we have $G=MN$

Comment: How does showing $M \cong G/N$ demonstrate that $MN \cong G$?